# Check if a sql view exists and then create it dynamically before altering it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I am trying check if a SQL Server view exists and if it doesn't exist, create a view with dynamic script and then alter it.

I am using the following script

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id,N'IsView') = 1)
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N' CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test] AS '
END
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[test]
---
---
```

The above script throws this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AS'.

May I know the correct way to do it?

Comment: Try adding a simple SELECT statement, like:   ' CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test] AS SELECT 0'

Comment: @TabAlleman That would work as a SPROC but views require a column name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CREATE` statement is incomplete. You can create the procedure by editing it to the following.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test] AS SELECT 1 'foo'
```

Once it is created, you can move on to altering it.

Edit: Fully escaped it will look like this:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N' CREATE VIEW [dbo].[test1] AS SELECT 1 ''foo'' '
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no actual view definition in your code. That being said, why not just drop the view if it **does** exist and then your code can just always create the view instead of trying to do an `ALTER`?

Comment: yeah but dropping a view will drop all the permissions for the users as we are creating a new view altogether

Comment: True, although I usually have permissions included as part of my deploy process or included as part of the object script, so it's not a problem for me. I suppose it all depends on how you're handling that.